# Wall-mounted toilet

Tags: toilet

I have a small bathroom that would greatly benefit from a wall-mounted toilet. Main need is to shift the bowl towards the wall to increase the open space.

I'd like a wall-mounted toilet option that doesn't require tearing out the wall. The house is elevated 12 feet, with the garage underneath the toilet area. The area underneath the toilet is completely open and accessible.

**Does a wall-mounted toilet exist that can have all of the non-visible parts installed *below* the toilet?** This obviously would imply non-gravity-fed approach.

Comment: https://www.build.com/product/summary/1559111?uid=3676763&jmtest=gg-gbav2_3676763&inv2=1&&source=gg-gba-pla_3676763!c1709211112!a69367404440!dc!ng&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-eeMBhCpARIsAAZfxZBzg7McffKp4MSzh1XuijLy8muTh3LdwdjtAIADPpa6MsvXQBHq9-QaAmcMEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of wall-mount pressure-flush toilets. Most any airport/rest area/stadium will have them.

Operating one in a home rather than a commercial environment may requite some clever plumbing hacks, since they expect a lot of water in a large pipe, but if you apply a pressure tank and large piping from the pressure tank to the toilet that can probably be made to work. A smaller pipe can refill the pressure tank between flushes.

I casually looked at them once and found them on the whole rather high priced. Merely getting the pipes in the wall is still going to require opening the wall, and providing adequate support to bolt the thing to may also require opening the wall.